# Unable to install proprietary drivers on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've been trying to install NVIDIA drivers on my Dell 7559 Ubuntu 14.04.5 with little success. The Additional Drivers menu doesn't apply the recommended drivers(reverts back to X.org) and I can't download drivers from PPA `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` because some packages cannot be authenticated.

Running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfdk-aac0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bbswitch-dkms libcuda1-387 nvidia-opencl-icd-387 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1 screen-resolution-extra
Suggested packages:
  bumblebee opencl-icd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bbswitch-dkms libcuda1-387 nvidia-387 nvidia-opencl-icd-387 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings ocl-icd-libopencl1 screen-resolution-extra
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 82,1 MB/82,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 374 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 bbswitch-dkms screen-resolution-extra
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

I did run `sudo apt-key update` and `sudo apt-get update` to try to solve the authentication problem, but with no success.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I just successfully installed NVIDIA drivers on my Asus 14.04.5 machine from that exact ppa. It would help with troubleshooting if you edited your question to show the exact error messages you received.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've added more information, hope it helps.

Comment: It appears that I got those 3 problematic packages out of the normal repos, not the ppa. I am not familar with this `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command.  I just added the ppa and did `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-settings`  (note that nvidia-387 may the correct package for your system, I do not know that)

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of the drivers work. Even so much so that my computer doesn't boot up anymore.